# How to get all ubuntu versions of software using python -apt

Tags: python, ubuntu, apt, deb

I have code (will post below) that pulls all the packages from apt-cache and then pulls each version of that package. For company reasons we are wanting to build a large corpus of data. From the below code it would appear that I am only getting packages that related to the current ubuntu os version that our cluster is running. I would like to iterate this process for older and newer versions of ubuntu. Is that possible with the python-apt module? If so what direction/command should I be looking at?

```
def main():
    print "Script Start"
    cache = apt.Cache()

    pkg32 = []  
    pkg64 = []
    pkgUnknown = []

    for item in cache:
      tempArch = item.architecture()
      if tempArch == 'amd64':
          for ver in item.versions:
              pkg64.append({'builder': 'ubuntuPackage', 'project': 'ubuntuPackage', })
              repoName = 'debpkg:' + item.shortname + '=' + ver.version
              pkg64[-1].update({'repourl': repoName})
              pkg64[-1].update({'buildID': 'Debian ' + repoName})
      elif tempArch == 'i386':
          for ver in item.versions:
              pkg32.append({'builder': 'ubuntuPackage', 'project': 'ubuntuPackage', })
              repoName = 'debpkg:' + item.shortname + '=' + ver.version
              pkg32[-1].update({'repourl': repoName})
              pkg32[-1].update({'buildID': 'Debian ' + repoName})
      else:
          for ver in item.versions:
              pkgUnknown.append({'builder': 'ubuntuPackage', 'project': 'ubuntuPackage', })
              repoName = 'debpkg:' + item.shortname + '=' + ver.version
              pkgUnknown[-1].update({'repourl': repoName})
              pkgUnknown[-1].update({'buildID': 'Debian ' + repoName})




    saveJson(pkg64, 'debian64List.json')
    saveJson(pkg32, 'debian32List.json')
    saveJson(pkgUnknown, 'debianUnknownList.json')
```

Comment: You should be able to add arbitrary repository sources using this: http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/aptsources.sourceslist.html

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good direction. Will get back later today with results.